# Looping through Multi-selected Listbox values to create and name workbook

Tags: excel, vba

The listbox is not assigning the selected values to "n". The "n" value is 0 regardless if I select values from the listbox or not.  I'm learning, so it could be something simple that I'm missing... suggestions?  Thanks!

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

With cbomonth
    .AddItem "January"
    .AddItem "February"
End With
With cboyear
    .AddItem "2013"
    .AddItem "2014"
End With
With cboteam
    .AddItem "Team1"
    .AddItem "Team2"
End With
With cbodocument
    .AddItem "Task1"
    .AddItem "Task2"
End With
With ListBox1
.AddItem "Name"
.AddItem "Name"
End With
cboteam.ListIndex = 0
cboyear.ListIndex = 4
cbomonth.ListIndex = 6
cbodocument.ListIndex = 1

End Sub

Private Sub cmdSubmit_Click()

    Dim year As String
    Dim month As String
    Dim days As Integer
    Dim team As String
    Dim n as Long
    Dim tallboxynames As Variant
    Dim tallynewfile As String

    Unload Me

    year = cboyear.Value
    month = cbomonth.Value
    team = cboteam.Value
    document = cbodocument.Value

    TallyPath = "\\network path\Tally of orders\Master Template\"
    TallyPath1 = "\\network path\Tally of orders\" & year & "\"
    TallyPath2 = "\\network path\Tally of orders\" & year & "\" & month & "\"
    TallyTemplate = "Tally_Template_ver1.xls"

If document = "Tally Sheets" Then
    For n = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If ListBox1.Selected(n) Then
            tallynewfile = ListBox1.Selected(n) & ".xls"
        Else
            MsgBox "No data from listbox"
        End If
If Len(Dir(TallyPath1, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
    MkDir TallyPath1
End If
If Len(Dir(TallyPath2, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
    MkDir TallyPath2
    FileCopy TallyPath & TallyTemplate, TallyPath2 & tallynewfile
End If
    Next n
End If
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: move Unload Me to the end before Exit Sub. Note that its better to hide userform on the click, and unload in the main module

Comment: Tried it with same result.  It's counting them and then 0 value for "n".  Same with Kaz's suggestion.

Comment: Adding to that.. I commented it out completely with the same result.

Comment: debug step by step then... print your Listbox1.ListCount see what the value is, then get inside your if statement see how it executes

Comment: I'm still working on this... just been too busy to get back to it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Move the **Unload Me to the end of the procedure**:

```
Private Sub cmdSubmit_Click()
    ' code here ...
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

To get the selected item **use Value if ListBox1.MultiSelect = 0** (fmMultiSelectSingle):

```
Me.ListBox1.Value
```

If **MultiSelect > 0 then use Selected property**, example:

```
Private Function GetSelectedItems() As String
    Dim text As String
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If Me.ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
            text = text & Me.ListBox1.List(i) & vbNewLine
        End If
    Next i
    MsgBox "Selected items are: " & text
    GetSelectedItemsText = text
End Function
```

Comment: This is correct and actually what I had.  Ultimately, it was an issue with a different module. bah.  I ended up getting it to work. :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
Unload Me
```

try to use

```
Me.Hide
```

When you `unload` all values on the form are deleted. They are kept if you use `Hide`.