# MSAccess VBA - Loop only through user-selected records

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to iterate through the records of a database, in order to save all of the attachments associated to certain fields of each record. I managed to find a way to properly export the attachments by cycling though the entire table. However, it would be way more useful to export only the attachments of the records previously **selected by the user** in the table form.

This is what my code structure looks like at the moment:

```
Public Function Main()
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset2
    Dim rsA As DAO.Recordset2
    Dim CRT As DAO.Field2
    Dim cat As DAO.Field2
    Dim prg As DAO.Field2
    Dim strFullPath As String
    Dim CatPrg As String
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject

    'Get the database, recordset, and attachment field
    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("Archieve_Table")
    Set STF = rst("STF")
    Set cat = rst("CAT")
    Set prg = rst("PRG")

    'Navigate through the table
    Do While Not rst.EOF
        CatPrg = cat.Value & "-" & prg.Value

        'Get the recordset for the Attachments field STF
        Set rsA = STF.Value
        'Save all attachments in the field
        Do While Not rsA.EOF
            strPath = CurrentProject.Path & "\Export\" & CatPrg & "\STF\"
            strFullPath = strPath & rsA("FileName")

            'Make sure the file does not exist and save
            If Dir(strFullPath) = "" Then
                rsA("FileData").SaveToFile strFullPath
            End If

            'Next attachment
            rsA.MoveNext
        Loop
        rsA.Close

        'Next record
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop

    rst.Close
    dbs.Close

    Set STF = Nothing
    Set rsA = Nothing
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing
    Set cat = Nothing
    Set prg = Nothing
End Function
```

Probably I need to add some conditions at `Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("Archieve_Table")` when I set the OpenRecordset.

Comment: How do users select records? Can open a filtered recordset with an SQL statement: `dbs.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Archieve_Table WHERE somecriteriahere")`. "Archieve" is a misspelling of "Archive".

Comment: The user can select the records by just clicking on a row. Is there a property or a statement that picks only the selected rows?

Comment: If your users are working directly in the table itself, you are limited and , IMO, bad practice. Use a form or a form with a subform. THEN you can iterate through the selected records. Even using a listbox to allow the user to select multiple records would work. Then a button to "Extract Attachments" or whatever

Comment: I have code that loops through continuously selected records on form similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669946/how-do-i-access-the-selected-rows-in-access. AFAIK, cannot do discontinuous selection on table or form. If you want to allow discontinuous selection, use a multi-select listbox (which can be unwieldy for a very large dataset) and loop through selected items https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15483591/looping-through-multi-selected-listbox-values-to-create-and-name-workbook.